# Convert ISO/UTC date to local by displaying timezone javascript/momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, momentjs

I have a date in the format like 2019-05-18T19:30:00-0400 which I need to display as **05/18/2019 07:30 PM EST** using momentjs or plain javascript. I tried several ways, for example, moment(new Date('2019-05-18T19:30:00-0400')).format('MM-DD-YYYY h:mm A zz')

Comment: I tried this, moment('2019-05-18T19:30:00-0700').format('DD/MM/YYYY h:mm A zz') which is displaying it like 18/05/2019 7:30 PM, but no timezone value

Comment: If you want to use plain JavaScript, have a look at [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString). If you want to use moment, have a look at [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), you could have something like: `moment.tz('2019-05-18T19:30:00-0400', 'America/New_York').format('MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A zz')`.  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40494995/4131048).

Comment: I do not know timezone (America/New_York) details when I get date string. It can be any date with any offset 2019-05-18T19:30:00+0100, if I use toLocaleString(), it is converting it to browser's timezone, not to the timezone that represents in date string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to determine a time zone from an offset alone.  There are many offsets that belong to more than one time zone.  Thus rendering an abbreviation is impossible.

See [Time Zone != Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) in the timezone tag wiki for further details, and refer to the [list of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) if you would like examples.

However, from your comments it appears you that you would also like to keep the same local time and offset as you are given.  Moment can help with that part, using its (inappropriately named) `parseZone` function:

```
moment.parseZone("2019-05-18T19:30:00+0100").format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A ZZ")
//=> "05/18/2019 07:30 PM +0100"
```